# Magento coupon code for multiple time use until offer value zero

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need a coupon code in magento. But the condition is one user can use the code more then one time. But cant't get more discount then code discount amount.

Like admin create a coupon code of $100 fixed amount. But my first order total $70. So if I use this code I will get $70 discount. For next when I use same code, I want $30 discount. That process will go until I get full amount($100) of discount.

Is that possible in magento?